# Showing the energy of states is positive in SUSY

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, supersymmetry

When we consider the energy of any state in supersymmetry we calculate:
$$
\langle\phi|\{Q^I_\alpha,\bar{Q}^I_{\dot{\alpha}}\}|\phi\rangle=2\sigma^\mu_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\langle\phi|P_\mu|\phi\rangle\delta^{II}
$$
$$
=\langle\phi|\left(Q^I_\alpha(Q^I_\alpha)^\dagger+(Q^I_\alpha)^\dagger Q^I_\alpha\right)|\phi\rangle
$$
$$
=||\;(Q^I_\alpha)^\dagger|\phi\rangle\;||^2+||\;Q^I_\alpha|\phi\rangle\;||^2 \ge0
$$
I understand that why we use the first equality from the superPoincarè algebra. I just dont understand how we arrive at the final equality. Since it is a sum of squared terms I understand that will be larger or equal to zero but how do we derive the final equality?

Comment: The definition of the adjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is very simple:
$$
\left(Q^I_\alpha |\phi\rangle\right)^\dagger = \langle \phi | (Q^I_\alpha)^\dagger
$$
So you have squared therms.

Did I correctly understand question?

Comment: Oh wow I'm blind, yes I'm really sorry I didn't see that.